# Json schema validator - validation not working as expected

Tags: json-schema-validator

I have tried to set up the validation schema so that if the field public in the request body is set to "public", then I validate that the fields title, description and tags are required, otherwise the request is valid, and this fields are not required. My json schema looks like this:

```
{  
 "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",  
 "title": "Update post",  
 "type": "object",  
 "properties": {    
   "public": {      
     "type": "string"    
    },    
    "title": {      
       "type": "string",      
       "minLength": 3    
    },    
    "description": {      
       "type": "string",      
       "minLength": 3    
    },    
    "tags": {      
       "type": "array",      
       "items": {        
         "type": "string"      
       },      
       "uniqueItems": true,      
       "minItems": 1    
    },    
    "attachmentUrl": {      
       "type": "string"    
    }  
  },  
  "anyOf": [{      
     "not": {        
       "properties": {          
         "public": { "enum": ["public"] } },        
     "required": ["public"]      
     }    
  },    
  { 
    "required": ["title", "description", "tags", "attachmentUrl"] 
  }],  
  "additionalProperties": true
}
```

But, this doesn't work as I want it to work. If I send a request body like this:

```
{
   "PK":"USER#auth0|223232006ede0b3f",
   "SK":"POST#8eab1dd5-4179-4f89-afc3-29af9e2732c1",
   "postId":"8eab1dd5-4179-4f89-afc3-29af9e2732c1",
   "userId":"auth0|5f8e2de69b8822006ede0b3f",
   "title":"Another post",
   "createdAt":"2020-10-20T23:54:37.172Z",
   "itemType":"POST",
   "public":"private",
   "publicPostId":"private#8eab1dd5-4179-4f89-afc3-29af9e2732c1",
   "tags":[],
   "attachmentUrl":"",
   "description":"some "
}
```

Then the request fails and I get the message:

> message: "Invalid request body"

But, if I send a request like this:

```
PK: "USER#auth0|1232132e69b8822006ede0b3f"
SK: "POST#8eab1dd5-4179-4f89-afc3-29af9e2732c1"
attachmentUrl: ""
createdAt: "2020-10-20T23:54:37.172Z"
description: "some "
itemType: "POST"
postId: "8eab1dd5-4179-4f89-afc3-29af9e2732c1"
public: "public"
publicPostId: "private#8eab1dd5-4179-4f89-afc3-29af9e2732c1"
tags: ["adsad"]
title: "Another post"
userId: "auth0|5f8e2de69b8822006ede0b3f"
```

Where public is set to "public", and other fields are not empty, then the request is valid. How can I fix this schema so that it is not valid only when the field is set to "public" and one of the fields description, tags or title are empty.
I have played around with json schema validator and I made this validation that works for my use case there:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Update post",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "tags": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "attachmentUrl": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "public": {
      "enum": ["public", "private"]
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": { "public": { "const": "public" } }
  },
  "then": { 
    "properties": {    
   "public": {      
     "type": "string"    
    },    
    "title": {      
       "type": "string",      
       "minLength": 3    
    },    
    "description": {      
       "type": "string",      
       "minLength": 3    
    },    
    "tags": {      
       "type": "array",      
       "items": {        
         "type": "string"      
       },      
       "uniqueItems": true,      
       "minItems": 1    
    },    
    "attachmentUrl": {      
       "type": "string"    
    }  
  }
  }
}
```

But, if I try to deploy this with serverless framework I get an error:

> An error occurred:
> ApiGatewayMethodPostsPostidVarPatchApplicationJsonModel - Invalid
> model specified: Validation Result: warnings : [Array schema should
> have property 'items' defined. Certain features, including SDK
> Generation, may not be supported for this schema], errors : [Invalid
> model schema specified. Unsupported keyword(s): ["if","then"]]
> (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
> BadRequestException; Request ID: 9571a7f1-83a9-45d9-bb33-ce9cd85f1d91;
> Proxy: null).

How can I make this work?